# How can I create Mega Menu In Divi?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I get this menu in Divi theme?:[image: theme]

Comment: I am just customizing the Divi theme, but didnt get the option to get the menu like this.

Comment: *If your question is very specific to WordPress then use Stack Exchange WordPress Q&A site.*

Answer (score 0):

Take these steps

1. Log in to your WordPress dashboard and go to Appearances > Menus. I assume you have a menu set up
2. I am assuming you have a menu that has a Menu item that is NOT a submenu let say it's called Features and under that you have submenus called Feature 1, Feature 2 etc.
3. Now in order to make your Megamenu you have to add a special CSS class to the main top tier link called “Features”. You can do that by clicking the screen options link of the top your page and making sure the CSS class option is checked.
4. Finally, you need to add a css class to the “Features” link you just created. Click the arrow on the right of the “Features” menu item to toggle the additional configuration options. Find the text box labeled CSS Classes and enter the class mega-menu

That's it basically. There is official documentation on how to do this